# Sequelize does not suport the MySQL 8 autentication protocol and I'm not getting how to change this protocol

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to migrate a db with Sequelize working with MySQL 8.0.15, but I'm not able to do that. I keep receiving this error message.

```
Sequelize CLI [Node: 10.15.0, CLI: 5.4.0, ORM: 5.3.5]

Loaded configuration file "config/config.json".
Using environment "development".

ERROR: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client
```

I've tried every single solution for this problem. The thing is when i try to change the MySQL root password the message i get is this one:

```
ERROR 1819 (HY000): Your password does not satisfy the current policy requirements
```

Then I did try to change the password validate policy following this procedure

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/validate-password-installation.html

then MySQL crashed cause it's deprecated. Then I tried this one

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/validate-password-installation.html

Then I got this

```
mysql> INSTALL COMPONENT 'file://component_validate_password';
ERROR 3529 (HY000): Cannot load component from specified URN: 
'file://component_validate_password'.
```

Then I checked where the component is

```
ls /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/component_v*
/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/component_validate_password.so
```

Anyone can help? I'm realy out of options, now!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use MySQL 5.x style authentication, typically all you have to do is add this to your `my.cnf`:

```
[mysqld]
default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password
```

Do this before adding any users. Only use users for connecting via Sequelize, never `root`.

Comment: It worked!!!! but one more thing why's this "Only use users for connecting via Sequelize, never root." @tadman?

Comment: What I mean is don't use "root" as your go-to account for access to the database. Use that only when adding or removing other users, as in for administration only. Sequelize should be connecting using an account specific to that project or application that's only got the necessary privileges, like it's constrained to the databases necessary for that application. `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON app_db.*` for example.

Comment: turned out it is working for a user, and still not working for the root. I still don't get it, but for now it is exactly what I need. Thanks a lot

Comment: This only applies to new users, not existing ones.

Comment: Ooh this explains a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL 8.0 then https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/validate-password-installation.html then this shouldn't work.

Have used mysql_secure_installation and installed the validate_password_component then?

If yes, in that case, the plugin must already be installed and all you need to do is set validate_password related parameters in the options file (default /etc/my.cnf) and some options require a server restart.

Answer (score 0):

For those who cannot edit system variables (for instance, if you're using a managed database in AWS or DigitalOcean), this works as well:

```
ALTER USER 'foo'@'bar' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
flush privileges;
```

Or, if you cannot run `flush privileges;` like me:

```
DROP USER 'foo'@'bar';
CREATE USER 'foo'@'bar' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
GRANT INSERT, SELECT, ... ON mydb.* TO 'foo'@'bar';
```